# How to reference the attached class from its mixin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mixins

I have the following mixin class and a host class, structured as follow:

```
class MyMixin:
    @staticmethod
    def preprocessIncomings(bliss, mod, **kw):
        my_logger(f"{__class__} is doing it's job now!")
        ....

class MyAttachedClass(MyMixin):
    ...
```

To my surprise, the logger doesn't reference to the `MyAttachedClass` as I intended. Instead it refers to the mixin class `MyMixin`.

Is there a way to reference to the host class from the mixin static method?

Comment: If the method needs access to the class, why is it static?

Comment: the whole point of a `staticmethod` is that it has no access to either instance or class state. the `__class__` is a special, lexically scoped closure variable inserted by the compiler, it always refers to the `__class__` where the function *is defined*, it's use intended for `super`. If you want access to the class that the method is being used on, use a regular instance method or a `classmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the good points in the comments: no, a `staticmethod` is specifically designed not to give you access to the instance or class from which it gets called, so there is no way to know from within `preprocessIncomings`  that it was called via `MyAttachedClass`. The `__class__` is a local variable, which you could view like a closure (i.e., it is got from the outer scope of where the code is defined).

You could maybe do more with `inspect.stack`, but the much more obvious solution is to change the method to a `classmethod`.